# Adding Rows and Auto Summing

Tags: worksheet-function

When I add rows to a excel sheet, I always have to check the sub-total to make sure my sheet captures the added rows.  Is there a auto function that will capture the added rows automatically with out double checking each time?

Comment: "When I add rows to a excel sheet, I always have to check the sub-total to make sure my sheet captures the added rows." **Why?**

Answer (score 0):

Autosum will not take into account if you insert a new row right before the autosum.

Let's say you have data on A1, A2 and A3, with A4 having the autosum. If you insert a new row before A1, A2 or A3 autosum will have it into account. However, if the new row is before A4, autosum, which now will be on A5, will only be adding A1 to A3.

Don't ask my why.